# Proving without the completeness theorem that variables can be renamed in Hilbert Calculus

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic, hilbert-calculus

> Prove without the completeness theorem that for every formula $A$ and variables $x,y,z$, it holds that 
>   $$\lnot\forall x\lnot A\left\{ x/z\right\} \vdash_{HC}\lnot\forall y\lnot A\left\{ y/z\right\} $$

The axioms we are given for

- Ax1 $A\to\left(B\to A\right)$
- Ax2 $\left(A\to\left(B\to C\right)\right)\to\left(\left(A\to B\right)\to\left(A\to C\right)\right)$
- Ax3 $\left(\lnot B\to\lnot A\right)\to\left(\left(\lnot B\to A\right)\to B\right)$
- Ax4 $\left(\forall xA\left(x\right)\right)\to A\left\{ t/x\right\}$  for a term $t$.
- Ax5 $\left(\forall x\left(A\to B\right)\right)\to\left(A\to\forall xB\right)$, where x is not free in A.

With two inference rules:

- MP Derive $B$ from $A$ and $A\to B$
- Gen Derive $\forall xA$ from $A$

We have also proven the Deduction, Dichotomey and Compactness theorems.

My issue is that I don't see much intuition behind the axioms, lacking any experience with these sort of proofs and as such have no idea even how to start. The fourth axiom looks the most relevant, so I assume I should first substitute and then generalize somehow, but then how do I deal with the negation signs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

1) $\forall y \ \lnot A[y/z]$   --- premise

2) $\lnot A[x/z]$ --- from 1) and Ax4 and *MP*

3) $\forall x \lnot A[x/z]$ --- from 2) by *Gen*

4) $\vdash \forall y \ \lnot A[y/z] \to \forall x \lnot A[x/z]$ --- from 1) and 3) by *Ded Th*

> 5) $\vdash \lnot \forall x \lnot A[x/z] \to \lnot \forall y \ \lnot A[y/z]$ --- by contraposition.

*Note* : contraposition is the tautology: $(A \to B) \to (\lnot B \to \lnot A)$.

The proof system is that of [Mendelson's textbook](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA31): you can find it as **Lemma 1.11 e)**, page 31.

---

*Comment*: how can we avoid the *Ded Th* ?.

Assume that $x$ is not free in $\forall y \ \lnot A[y/z]$.

By Ax4: $\vdash \forall y \ \lnot A[y/z] \to \lnot A[x/z]$ and by *Gen*: $\vdash \forall x \ (\forall y \ \lnot A[y/z] \to \lnot A[x/z])$.

By Ax5: $\vdash \forall y \ \lnot A[y/z] \to \forall x \ \lnot A[x/z]$; then contrapose to get: $\vdash \lnot \forall x \ \lnot A[x/z] \to \lnot \forall y \ \lnot A[y/z]$.

Comment: That definitely put me on the right track, thank you very much! Only thing I'm uncertain about now is the use of the deduction theorem. Isn't it limited in HC to cases where $\forall y \lnot A [y/z]$ is a sentence? Because I am not given that..

Comment: @Nescio - it depends on the "fine details" of the proof system; see [Mendelson](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA72) page 72.

Comment: unfortunately it is not part of the free preview by Google. Will need to try and get a hold on it..

Comment: @Nescio - sorry... I can see it. In any case, the relevant Corollary is: If a deduction showing that $Γ, B ⊢ C$ involves **no** application of *Gen* of which the quantified variables is free in $B$, then $Γ ⊢ B \to C$.

Comment: I see. This is indeed stronger than the version we have proven and I will look into it. Thank you very much anyway!